# What does $p = P(X_1 < X_2 > X_3 < X_4)$ mean?

Tags: probability

It is a question 59 on page 87 from Ross's book (Introduction to Probability Models)

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are independent continuous random variables with a common distribution function F and let

$p = P(X_1 < X_2 > X_3 < X_4)$

Just as the Title, what does it mean? 
Or similar questions with such an inequity?

Thanks

**Update 1**:

The solution says:
**Use the fact that F(Xi) is a uniform (0,1) random variable to obtain.** 
But where is **this fact**?

**Update:** A similar question

[How can I compute an expression for $P(X_1>X_2>X_3>X_4)$ if $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are normal and mututally independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782234/how-can-i-compute-an-expression-for-px-1x-2x-3x-4-if-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-ar)

BTW

I am not a native-English speaker, and I am learning it by myself.

Comment: Usually, a "multiple" inequality is a conjucntion: $X_1 < X_2 > X_3$ is $X_1 < X_2$ and $X_2 > X_3$.

Comment: Of course "$X_1 < X_2 > X_3 < X_4$" means "$X_1 < X_2$ and $X_2 > X_3$ and $X_3 < X_4$".

Comment: Or maybe a typo and is $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4)$

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct name of the book? Ross has a book called "Introduction to Probability Models" and there are many different editions.

Comment: @Jack Yes. 11th Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a rather unconventional use of inequalities as GEdgar points out in his comment and there is no typo. The "chain" of inequalities $X_1<X_2>X_3<X_4$ means *all* of the following hold:
$$
X_1<X_2,\ \  X_2>X_3,\ \  X_3<X_4.
$$

Here is the original problem:

> [image]

Here is the [official solution](http://math2.uncc.edu/~imsonin/Ross_Probability10ed_Student_Solutions2010.pdf) by Ross:

> [image]

<sup>Thanks to http://math2.uncc.edu/~imsonin/Ross_Probability10ed_Student_Solutions2010.pdf</sup>

Comment: Thanks. How do you know F(X_i) is a uniform distribution function?

Comment: @evergreenhomeland: this is a very instructive exercise. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

It's the probability that $X_1$ is less than $X_2$ AND that $X_2$ is greater than $X_3$ AND that $X_3$ is less than $X_4$. That's all.